# SSAS: alter cube objects automatically

Tags: ssas

i need to fill cube description field in multiple dimensions. I can execute alter xmla query in manual mode (in Management Studio), but how to automate this routine? There should be something like cycle, that iterates over all dims, get xml of dim, substitute  tag with value and run alter xmla query. First of all, i want to figure out how to get xml of cube object. Not manually via Management Studio GUI, but in query.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.